# how can calling of admin controller of custom module be done

Tags: php, magento, plugins, module, controller

How can I call admin controller of custom module using the following code. I have tried to search on Google but was unable to find anything

Here is the code of Mynamespace/TypeChanger/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Grid.php

```
class Mynamespace_TypeChanger_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
{
        protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        parent::_prepareMassaction();

        // Append new mass action option
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
                'typechanger',
                array('label' => $this->__('Change Type'),
                        'url'   => $this->getUrl('abc'),
        //this should be the url where there will be mass operation

            'additional' => array(
                        'visibility' => array(
                                'name' => 'type',
                                'type' => 'select',
                                'class' => 'required-entry',
                                'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Type'),
                                'values' => array('simple' => 'simple','grouped' => 'grouped' , 'configurable' => 'configurable' ,'virtual'=> 'virtual', 'bundle'=> 'bundle', 'downloadable'=>'downloadable')
                            )

            )

            )
            );
    }
}
```

here is the code for config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Mynamespace_TypeChanger>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </Mynamespace_TypeChanger>
        </modules>

        <admin>
            <routers>
                <typechanger>
                    <use>admin</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Mynamespace_TypeChanger</module>
                        <frontName>abc</frontName>
                    </args>
                </typechanger>
            </routers>

        </admin>

       <global>
            <blocks>
                <adminhtml>
                    <rewrite>
                        <catalog_product_grid>Mynamespace_TypeChanger_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
                    </rewrite>
                </adminhtml>
            </blocks>

        <helpers>
                <typechanger>
                    <class>Mynamespace_TypeChanger_Helper</class>
                </typechanger>
        </helpers>

        </global>

    </config>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add url tag in your Grid.php like below

```
 $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
                'typechanger',
                array('label' => $this->__('Change Type'),
                      'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massChangeType', array('_current'=>true)),
        //this should be the url where there will be mass operation

            'additional' => array(
                        'visibility' => array(
                                'name' => 'type',
                                'type' => 'select',
                                'class' => 'required-entry',
                                'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Type'),
                                'values' => array('simple' => 'simple','grouped' => 'grouped' , 'configurable' => 'configurable' ,'virtual'=> 'virtual', 'bundle'=> 'bundle', 'downloadable'=>'downloadable')
                            )    
                 )    
               )
            );
```

where your controller name should be like

```
Mynamespace_TypeChanger_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
```

anb path should be like

```
\Mynamespace\TypeChanger\controllers\Adminhtml\Catalog\ProductController.php
```

in that you have to define function `massChangeType` or your custom name.

And use below rewrite admin controller in `config.xml`

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mynamespace_TypeChanger before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mynamespace_TypeChanger_Adminhtml</Mynamespace_TypeChanger>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```